# FBA : Force windows authentication prompt

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, sign-in

I've been asking this request, but I can't seem to find a relevant answer...

I need to implement a custom sign-in page for external users and internal users (SharePoint 2013).

I enabled and congigured the FBA in order to be able to set a custom sign-in page.
However, my bosses don't want the users to use FBA at all, but stick to windows authentication only : they want the user to type his windows DOMAIN\username and password, and then get access to the SharePoint site.
But when I use the windows authentication option, should I be authorized to access the site, I'm automatically logged-in.

Is there a way to bypass this behaviour, to force the user to type in his windows username + password ?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to user input the their windows credential? do you have both authentication in One zone( windows and FBA) if yes then user will get the option select from one

Comment: The thing is that when you choose windows credentials, you are automatically logged in. My management wants to prevent that. They want the users to manually enter their windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate zone for the Web Application where you want to use FBA. By implementing FBA, you're removing the Windows Integrated Authentication mechanism where by the server response to the browser that authentication is required.